# In Unity, how can I take pictures with AR Camera and save images? (android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing an AR Camera app (android) using Unity AR Foundation, how can I take pictures with AR Camera and save images?

If you click the button with the code below, I even took a screenshot of the screen, but the "Path" setting doesn't work well.
I'd like to have the screenshot PNG file saved in the folder within the Unity project.

```
public Camera camera;   

private int resWidth;
private int resHeight;
string path;

void Start()
{
    resWidth = Screen.width;
    resHeight = Screen.height;
    path = "../ScreenShot/";
    Debug.Log(path);
}

public void ClickScreenShot()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    string name;
    name = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png";
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
    camera.targetTexture = rt;
    Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    Rect rec = new Rect(0, 0, screenShot.width, screenShot.height);
    camera.Render();
    RenderTexture.active = rt;
    screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
    screenShot.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
    File.WriteAllBytes(name, bytes);
}
```

Comment: You could use Application.dataPath so it saves in different location based on the platform. You could also want to allow access to the gallery so that the result can be used out of the application (this requires authorization from user). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

Comment: The path error was resolved using "Application.dataPath". However, the image file is not stored in the corresponding path folder... What should I do?